In imperative sentences, is it correct to use a full infinitive (to do) instead of a bare
Is it correct to use a full infinitive (to do) instead of a bare infinitive (do)?
I am an esl Chinese resident. And I read a comment, of which the commentator thinks I am benighted. (But I admit it's somewhat a reckless comment partially due to my nonlearnedness.):

History is the past of human knowledge. To learn more before your comment. Thanks.

Do you call that a complete sentence or just a part of a sentence? Is right to write an imperative starting with To?

The second one is not a complete sentence. Is it supposed to mean "You should learn more before you comment"?

"... read a comment in which the commentator thinks I am benighted".

benighted? What's that please?

@Lambie https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benighted

@AndyBonner I know what the word means. I don't think it works here.

@Lambie Agreed, but I think there's merit in leaving some mis-usages unaddressed when they're not part of the central question. This user acknowledges their beginning level, and it can be confusing to try to address everything at once.

@AndyBonner I disagree since I have no idea what he really means.

@Lambie Oh, I thought it was clear enough: "the commentator thinks I don't know enough." As supported by the direct quote.

For imperative sentences, no. A bare infinitive form. From Grammarly (amended):

Imperative sentence structure
Imperative sentences nearly always start with the imperative form of verbs.
Imperative forms of verbs are the root forms of verbs [that is, in form, bare infinitives] that, when followed by the objects of their sentences, form imperative
sentences.
Take a look at the imperative verbs bolded in these examples:

Follow me.
Go back to school.
Walk on the right side of the pathway.

[Sometimes, the verb is not simplex; below, 'make sure' = 'ensure':

Make sure you understand why we do this exercise.
Find out where that guy lives. {'find out' = 'ascertain'; 'discover'}]

[Negative commands use do-support:

Do not lean out of the window.
Don't stop!]

As you can see, the verb usually comes first in an imperative
sentence. But this isn’t always the case:

Please don’t spoil the movie.

Typically, the subject of an imperative sentence is implied [the addressee/s].
In some imperative sentences, an indirect object also follows the
verb. In others, there is no indirect object. And in some imperative
sentences, like these, the verb is the entire sentence:

Go.
Stop!
Run!

An imperative sentence always ends with either a period or an
exclamation point.


The term 'imperative verbs' is misleading since it implies that they are a special category of verb, whereas imperative clauses use a plain form, the same form that is used in infinitivals and subjunctives.

Not my d/v, btw.

Agree totally. Further amended.

But imperative sentences include negatives (prohibitions), and what some call phrasal verbs (as this term is defined in different ways, I usually stick to 'multi-word verbs') (which those who don't like the [find out] = [ascertain] etc analysis reject).

@EdwinAshworth I don't understand your last comment, but yes: imperatives may indeed be negative, as may declaratives and interrogatives. Which is why 'negative' is not a clause type.

I see 'make sure' (= 'ensure') in 'Make sure you understand why we do this exercise' as best treated as a single lexeme (a MWV), BillJ. I know CGEL rejects open compounds, but very many accept them, especially open compound nouns.

Thanks. I know that such usage is nonstandard now, but I also realize we come across such usage from time to time without realizing it.

Thanks. I understand that such usage is nonstandard now, but I also realize we come across such usage from time to time without realizing it. Comments can be nonstandard at times. Also, I spot this sentence pattern elsewhere:'' To the Virgins: To Make Much of Your Time'' (1648) by Robert  Herrick has To in an imperative. This also appears in short simple sentences:'' To be happy. '' and the likes of that.

But the verbal idiom "make sure" cannot be a single lexeme. It's just "make" that is a verb ("sure" is an adjective): this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have "They made sure it was locked", not *"They make sured it was locked".

The second part is not a complete sentence.   An imperative would qualify as a complete sentence but shouldn’t start with to.
The following would be grammatical, with the second sentence an imperative:

History is the past of human knowledge. Learn more before you comment.

The connection between the two sentences, however, isn’t obvious, but that is not part of this question.

First half of your answer was fine, but the second half "If we must retain to..." is not at all clear.  How does "to learn more before you comment" follow grammatically from the assertion "History is the past of human knowledge"?  How does the colon make it OK?

Thanks, @TimR.  My earlier line which said The connection between the two sentences, however, isn’t obvious, but that is not part of this question was meant to say the two parts are not semantically connected, but I didn’t express it well.  Then I also erroneously thought I wouldn’t need to repeat that in part two.  (Though the main problem was that I didn’t express well the disconnect.) Sure, History is the past of human knowledge: (to) learn more before you comment has the same semantic disconnect between the clause before the colon and the infinitive.

I was just focusing on the sentence structure, in how to convert the two-sentence type to a single-sentence one incorporating a colon.  That exercise is moot.  I have hence deleted that entire part of my answer as I see no point building something from the two lines of the original text that make no sense when used together.
